# Не могу как понять работу messeage.pin() в vk_api?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Вообщем ни как не могу понять как закреплять сообщение в беседе ботом, нужно что бы бот пересылал и закреплял сразу, может кто-нибудь может поделится примером работы message.pin() буду признателен !

Comment: [messages.pin](https://vk.com/dev/messages.pin). Что конкретно у Вас не получается? Вы что-то уже пробовали?

Comment: я не могу разобрать с message_id я так понимаю в него нужно поместить id сообшение,но где его взять?

Answer (score 0):

Если быстро и по тупому, то вот:

```py
import requests

token = 'твой токен тут'
group_id = 'id беседы тут'
message_id = 'id сообщения тут'

url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.pin?peer_id='+group_id+'&message_id='+message_id+'&access_token='+token+'&v=5.103'

response = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Спасибо, а откуда взялось это https://api.vk.com/method/messages.pin?

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/messages.pin

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/api_requests

Comment: А Вы пробовали подставлять какой-нибудь `message_id`?

Comment: А это уже совсем другой вопрос :-)

Comment: а как получить id сообщения это понять еще не могу  ?

Comment: @YoungProgrammer А это важно :-) Все сообщения, которые бот получает из беседы, имеют `id=0`, метод `getHistory` для беседы вызвать нельзя. И как тогда крепить то, чего нет?

Comment: значит закреп не как нельзя сделать через сообщество только через пользователя ?

Comment: Сообщения из беседы имеют поле `"conversation_message_id"`. Возможно, используя этот `id`, получится закрепить сообщение.

Comment: а можно по подробнее пожалуйста про по conversation_message_id